# Implementing a "refresh button" for parsing a JSONArray

Tags: android, android-json

I currently have a program that can parse a JSONArray and put each item into a listview.  But if you add something to the JSONArray the listview doesn't update until you run the app again. So how would I go about being able to update the listview when new items are added to the JSONArray. Here is the code I have that parses the JSONArray:

```
public class jarray extends Activity {

ArrayList<Actors> actorsList;

ActorAdapter adapter;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_jarray);
    actorsList = new ArrayList<Actors>();
    new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://bisonsoftware.us/hhs/messages.json");

    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new ActorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, actorsList);

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

}



class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(jarray.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
        dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {

            //------------------>>
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("messages");


                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {


                    Actors actor = new Actors();

                    String message = jarray.getString(i);
                    actor.setName(message);


                    //actorsList.add(actor);
                    adapter.add(actor);


                }
                return true;
            }

            //------------------>>

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        dialog.cancel();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if (result == false)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}

}
```

If you need any more of my code or just need some more explanation feel free to ask. Could really use some help on this, thanks.

Here is the ActorAdapter code:

```
public class ActorAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Actors> {
ArrayList<Actors> actorList;
LayoutInflater vi;
int Resource;
ViewHolder holder;

@Override
public void add(Actors object) {
    super.add(object);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public ActorAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Actors> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    vi = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    Resource = resource;
    actorList = objects;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // convert view = design
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
        holder.tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);

        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    holder.tvName.setText(actorList.get(position).getName());

    return v;

}

static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView tvName;

}

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't update until you run the app again?"

Comment: If I add something to the JSONArray it doesn't appear on the listview until I rerun the application/program.

Comment: post your ActorAdapter adapter

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding directly to the ArrayList, try adding it from your adapter.

You need to instantaite your `ActorAdapter` before running your `AsyncTask`

**sample:**

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_jarray);
actorsList = new ArrayList<Actors>();

adapter = new ActorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, actorsList);
ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);

new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://bisonsoftware.us/hhs/messages.json");

button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
```

When you add items to the adapter call the add method of the adapter not your arrayList

**change this:**

```
actorsList.add(actor);
```

**to:**

```
adapter.add(actor);
```

**Add** this in you `ActorAdapter` adapter:

```
    @Override
public void add(Actors object) {
    super.add(object);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**change you oncreate into this:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_jarray);
    actorsList = new ArrayList<Actors>();

    adapter = new ActorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, actorsList);
    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://bisonsoftware.us/hhs/messages.json");

    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

}
```

Comment: When I added the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); it crashed the app when I ran it. Would you have any idea why it would do this?

Comment: @user3358306 try removing it and overried ur add method of ur adapter

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, could you elaborate?

Comment: @user3358306 see edit above.. and dont use the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Wait what part of actoradapter should I add that into?

Comment: @user3358306 it is a method like getView.

Comment: It seemed to crash the application when I ran it again. Do you have any more ideas on a solution?By the way thanks for helping me.

Comment: I edited the code in my original post but logcat isn't working right and isn't posting my error for some reason.

Comment: @user3358306 post your jarray class again.

Answer (score -1):

The way you update a listview is by remaking the adapter with the updated information, setting the listadapter and then calling `NotifyDataSetChanged()`.  This tells the device to refresh the layout.

```
ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new ActorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, actorsList);

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I added that but it seemed to not work. I also had adapter.NotifDataSetChanged(); in onPostExecute. Maybe I'm just doing it wrong, do you think you could elaborate on this solution?

Comment: When you created the new ActorAdapter, did you create it with the new actor data?  If not, the call 'NotifyDataSetChanged()' will just change adapter to the state it is already in.